# Eloquent event is not firing

Tags: php, eloquent

I want to set the password when it changes in my User model. So I'm using boot method of the model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public static function boot()
    {
        //die('here'); // this happens
        User::saving(function ($user) {
            //die('here'); // this doesn't happen
            if ($user->isDirty('password')) {
                $user->password = // hash password...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using the save() method on the model to create the entry in the data base, apparently this should fire the creating event. I've emptied the database table to ensure that a new row is being creating (it is), this event does not fire - and my password is raw un-ecrypted. By the way, I'm using illuminate/database ^5.2 in my app (not Laravel).

UPDATE - capsule initialization

```
$capsule = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'database' => 'mydb',
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypass',
]);
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Comment: Did you set an event dispatcher on the capsule? Can you show your capsule initialization code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Hm, not that I'm aware of. I've updated my post with the capsule initialize.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want your events to work, you need to setup an event dispatcher for the capsule.

First, you will need to add `illuminate/events` to your dependencies. Add `"illuminate/events": "5.2.*"` to your `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    // other requires...
    "illuminate/events": "5.2.*"
},
```

Next, you'll need to setup the event dispatcher on the capsule. Make sure you do this before your call to `bootEloquent()`. From the [docs](https://github.com/illuminate/database#usage-instructions):

```
// new capsule...

// add connection...

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Now you should be good to go.

While not related, I also wanted to point out that your `boot` method should make sure to call `parent::boot();` before it does anything else (like setting up events).

---

**Optional solution**

If this is the only thing you're trying to do with the events, you can skip this altogether by setting up a [mutator function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for your `password` attribute. The mutator method will be called any time you assign a value to the mutated attribute (i.e. `$user->password = "hello"`).

To do this, just add the following function to your `User` model:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! Yes your optional solution is better for my password, other attributes the boot() method works well with now. I didn't realize I had to use parent::boot() too, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and this how i solved it :

**1** 
First thing i made sure to require all the necessary  packages :

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "~5.2",
        "illuminate/events": "~5.2",
    }
}
```

**2**
Then I had to setup correctly My DB connection

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => "driver",
    'host'      => "host",
    'database'  => "database",
    'username'  => "username",
    'password'  => "password",
    'charset'   => "charset",
    'collation' => "collation",
    'prefix'    => "prefix",
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

**3**
After , I Used a Trait since it is a perfect solution to clean up the models

```
trait ModelTrait{

    public static function bootModelTrait()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            // Create Event Here
        });
    }
}
```

**4**
Then i used the trait in every Model

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    use ModelTrait;

}
```